# Java argument is unrecognized

Tags: java, jvm, arguments

I'm trying to start another Java process from
my jar, and I'm using a ProcessBuilder:

```
File javaHome = new File(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin");
List<String> javaList = new ArrayList<String>();

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
processBuilder.directory(serverDir);
{
    javaList.add(javaHome + File.separator + "java");
    javaList.add("-XX:MaxPermSize=512m");
    javaList.add("-Xmx2048M");

    // -Djava.library.path="natives-win-x64/"
    javaList.add(
        String.format(                          
            "-Djava.library.path=\"natives-%s-%s/\"", 
            //Get system os, 
            //Get system arch
        )
    );

    {
        String classPath = new String();
        for (File library : scanLibrary(new File(serverDir, "libraries"))) {
            String libPath = library.getPath();
            classPath += libPath + ";";
        }

        classPath += new File(new File(serverDir, "binary"), "MainJar.jar").getPath();
        javaList.add("-classpath \\\"" + classPath + "\\\" ");
    }

    javaList.add("my.other.jar.main.class");
}
processBuilder.command(javaList);
processBuilder.start();
```

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: 
-classpath "C:\Absoulte\Path\Library.jar;C:\Absoulte\Path2\Library2.jar;C:\Absoulte\Path3\Library3.jar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `--classpath "..."` as a single argument. I believe you should specify it as two arguments:

```
javaList.add("-classpath");
javaList.add("\\\"" + classPath + "\\\");
```

(It's not clear to me whether you really need all those backslashes, by the way... you may well find that just `javaList.add(classPath)` is enough, or maybe `javaList.add("\"" + classPath + "\"")`.)